# More control on raster colour maps?

Tags: qgis, raster, qgis-2.10, colormap

I'm playing with various raster layers (DEM, geophysical data such as gravity or gamma-ray, etc). QGIS does a fine job at reading and displaying them, but I'm looking for more control on symbology, effectively similar to what is allowed for graduated symbology for vectors, such as defining breaks for equal intervals, equal counts, etc... So far the raster coulour table only allow one option (seems to be equal interval).

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Well the question is, "is there a solution to get finer control on color table" : a menu item or checkbox I missed perhaps, or a plugin...

Comment: Are you talking about an actual color table that is stored as part of the raster and displayed using the paletted renderer, or the single band pseudocolor renderer where you can define continuous, equal interval or manual class breaks?

Comment: I was actually thinking of the pseudocolour renderer. It is true that you can define equal continuous or equal interval breaks, and my point is that I'm looking for options similar to the vector renderer : classify using e.g. equal counts, or indeed any gain curve I want.   However, since you mention it, one workaround would be a plugin (or other kind of external function ?) generating e.g. a tiff with a built-in colourtable, according to certain rules -- it would be statitc and hence less useful, but better than nothing !